# MCSession how to stream UIImages with NSStream

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsstream, mcsession

I'am trying to send UIImages each second over NSStream

but i get a crash when decoding on

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:len];
```

*Uncaught exception: *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x62, 0x70, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x73, 0x74, 0x30, 0x30)*

looks like the data is corrupted / incomplete, due to bad handling

**- i'am not sure if i supposed to create a new stream, each time i want to send an image**

**- i'am not sure about the decoding, especially about the buffer size (and how to make it work by having the size variable)**

// to send an UIImage each sec

```
- (void)sendStreamImage:(UIImage *)image withOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {

    NSError * error;
    NSOutputStream *outputStream = [self.session startStreamWithName:@"SnapClapStream" toPeer:[self.session.connectedPeers firstObject] error:&error];
    // handle error if present

    outputStream.delegate = self;
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream open];

    NSData * imageData = ...
    NSDictionary * dictionary = @{@"imageData":imageData, @"orientation":@(orientation)};
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary];
    [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
}
```

In the stream delegate

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {

    if (eventCode == NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable) {

        if (![aStream isKindOfClass:[NSInputStream class]]) {
            return;
        }

        NSInputStream * inputStream = (NSInputStream *)aStream;

        NSInteger bufferSizeNumber = (25 * 1024);
        NSMutableData *myBuffer = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:bufferSizeNumber];

        uint8_t *buffer = [myBuffer mutableBytes];
        NSInteger len = 0;

        while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
            len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:bufferSizeNumber];
            if (len > 0) {

                NSData * data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:len];
                NSDictionary * dictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
                dictionary = [self processReceivedDictionary:dictionary];

                // thats it, dictionary should contain all the data

            }
        }

    } else if (eventCode == NSStreamEventEndEncountered) {

        ...

    }

}
```